# HasMany RESTfull Implementation

Tags: design, architecture, rest, url

So I've been reading a lot on RESTfull design - specifically dealing with resources.

Taking the canonical example of **Users**, **Posts**, and **Comments**, with relationships as:

> Users ---(hasMany)---> Post ---(hasMany)---> Comment

One may initially think to expose something like:

```
GET /users               GET /posts               GET /comments 
POST /users              POST /posts              POST /comments 
GET /users/id            GET /posts/id            GET /comments/id
PUT /users/id            PUT /posts/id            PUT /comments/id
DELETE /users/id         DELETE /posts/id         DELETE /comments/id
```

But then, say I want all *Comments* of a certain *Post* made by a particular *User*. I'd need to do something like:

```
GET /users/id
   > someUser
   > var postIds = someUser.posts()
GET /posts?id=<postIds[0]>&id=<postIds[1]>&...
   > somePosts
   >  **application user inspects posts to see which one they care about**
   > var postOfInterest = somePosts[x]; 
   > var postId = postOfInterest.id;
GET /comments?id=postId
   > someComments (finally)
```

Suppose though I only care about a *Post* or *Comment* in the context of it's owner. Suppose a different resource structuring which may (or may not?) be more natural:

```
GET /users
POST /users  
GET /users/id   
PUT /users/id
DELETE /users/id

GET /users/id/posts
POST /users/id/posts
GET /users/id/posts/id
PUT /users/id/posts/id
DELETE /users/id/posts/id

GET /users/id/posts/id/comments
POST /users/id/posts/id/comments
GET /users/id/posts/id/comments/id
GET /users/id/posts/id/comments/id
GET /users/id/posts/id/comments/id
```

Which to me, is probably a better representation of what the resources are. Then all I need is:

```
GET /users/id/posts
   > somePosts
   > **application user inspects posts to see which one they care about**
   > var postOfInterest = somePosts[x];
   > var postId = postOfInterest.id;
GET /users/id/posts/postId/comments
   > someComments
```

This just seems more like navigating a file system than the previous method - but I don't know if its RESTfull at all (perhaps this is what REST was trying to *get rid of*) because in order to access a *Comments* resource, I need to know which *User* and which *Post* it belongs to. But the former requires 3 requests, while the latter requires just 2.

Thoughts?

Comment: I'm also going to post this on SO, because, frankly, I don't know where this post belongs

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know what you're describing, essentially nested resources, is perfectly RESTful. You might want to keep the resources such as '/posts/id' and '/comments/id' in-case you want to get post/s or comment/s without knowing which user you're looking at, but there's nothing wrong with also nesting them inside each other for getting the posts for a particular user or comments for a particular post.

Rails in particular allows you to easily nest resources in this manner by doing something like the following in your routes configuration:

```
resources :users do
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

Comment: Cool - least I know it's not evil. But would it be evil to use both approaches? I.e using the latter case generally, but exposing convenience routes to access representations of sub-directories irrespective of their context? I.e `/posts`

Answer (score 2):

When exposing a RESTful interface, you also need to examine, what the interface is telling the user.

When examining a `post`, its more than likely a user doesn't care about who made it and unless `post` IDs are only unique in the scope of a user (which is unlikely) its just addtional cruft in the URL. While its true that a `post` *has a* user, I'm not so sure you can say that in this context it is *owned* by its user, if the difference is clear.

There is also the abiquity of what happens when user X writes a post, and user Y writes a comment on that post. In this `/users/idZ/post/id/comment/id` does idZ refer to the user who wrote the post, or the comment? Moreso, why do you need to know the user, if you already have a post or comment ID?

Alternatively, a comment *is* owned by its post, even if its ID is globally unique.

Lastly, there is a readability difference between `users` and `user`, with the latter implying discreteness. Similarly, with `posts` and `post`, and `comments` and `comment`.

So personally, given this, I'd use these actions (with the appropriate verbs where required):

```
ACTION /users
ACTION /user/id   

ACTION /user/id/posts    # A user owns these posts
ACTION /post/id          # But the site owns this particular post

ACTION /post/id/comments
ACTION /post/id/comments/id
```

Comment: Interesting approach - I agree with your argument of *has* vs *owns*. In my particular case, my model-structures are hierarchical with strict ownership of node->childnode in hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Colin, I guess the point you're discussing is about nested REST and that is completely possible with the interface.

Users ---(hasMany)---> Post ---(hasMany)---> Comment

This relationship do exist, but how you defined them in next two cleared the purpose of nested representations. I designed this code under [REST nested designs](http://docs.espressologic.com/docs/logic-designer/database) in this page as a demo reference, you can check them too.